# Converting cells into colnames

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

There's the exmaple of my dataframe:

```
> df
n   b    c    d
A Eeee Aaaa     
B Aaaa Bbbb Jjjj
C Jjjj Cccc     
D Aaaa Dddd
```

I want to convert the cells' values into unique colnames and fill the dataframe with binary values, so the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
> resulting_df
n   Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Eeee Jjjj
A    1    0    0    1    0
B    1    1    0    0    1
C    0    0    1    0    1
D    0    0    0    0    0
```

I'm sure there should be an easy way to accomplish this without loops. Please, help.

Comment: Well you tagged it `reshape2`, but did you try the package?

Comment: @RichScriven yes, I'm exploring it at the moment but yet can't figure out what function to use. I suppose I need smth like spread() from tidyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reshape2` can do that:
Data:

```
df=structure(list(n = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Aaaa", 
"Eeee", "Jjjj"), class = "factor"), c = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Aaaa", 
"Bbbb", "Cccc", "Dddd"), class = "factor"), d = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), .Label = "Jjjj", class = "factor")), .Names = c("n", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df,id.vars = "n"),n ~value,fun.aggregate = length)
```

Which gives:

```
  n Aaaa Bbbb Cccc Dddd Eeee Jjjj NA
1 A    1    0    0    0    1    0  1
2 B    1    1    0    0    0    1  0
3 C    0    0    1    0    0    1  1
4 D    1    0    0    1    0    0  1
```

You could then unselect the last column.

The idea is to `melt()` the data into a long format and then recast it according to your need with `dcast()`.
`fun.aggregate=length`is used so that the values used to fill the dataframe correspond to the number of occurences.